# change default gumby style button

Tags: html, css

I am in a gumby project and use gumby's defalut style.

I've got a gumby button below:

[image]

Here is the code for it:

```
<div class="large primary btn"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter now " id="register-submit" href="#entry"></input></div>
```

I am just wondering, how to style it to following style:

[image]

The problem is, "Enter Now" is the value of the button. Any idea of to achieve this?
Would like to keep this gumby style, but don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know:

```
<div class="large primary btn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter now " id="register-submit" href="#entry">
</input>
<P style="text-align:center;>To input your unique game card code on the next page</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="large primary btn">
    <button type="submit" name="submit"id="register-submit" href="#entry">
        <b>Enter now</b><br/>
        <span style="font-size:12px;">To do something</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use purely css to achive this you could use the `after` psuedo element like so:

```
.primary input:after{
    content:'To input your unique game card code on the next page';
}
```

If you want to add the text in the HTML look at the anwer Joy_S gave.